# React: React Testing Library finishes test before setTimeout in component's useEffect executes

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I need to test if Modal was closed. When user clicks submit button, store changes and modal will be  closed in 250-300ms. But it stays on 'screen' in RTL.

```
test("testname", async () => {
  const user = userEvent.setup();
  const { store } = renderWithProviders(<App />);
  const editBtn = screen.getByTestId("edit-item");
  await user.click(editBtn); //<-- opens popup
  const editPopupInput = screen.getByTestId("edit-popup-input");
  const savePopupBtn = screen.getByTestId("save-popup-btn");
  expect(editPopupInput).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(savePopupBtn).toBeInTheDocument();
  await user.type(editPopupInput, 'text');
  expect(editPopupInput).toHaveValue('text');
  await user.click(await screen.findByTestId("save-popup-btn"));
  expect(store.getState().data.items[0].title).toEqual('text'); //<-- click worked well
  await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => screen.getByTestId("save-popup-btn"), { //<-- breaks
    timeout: 1000,
  }); 
});
```

Maybe I use 'waitForElementToBeRemoved' wrong (I found it in docs). 
App works fine. 
All tests in my file work fine, only this fails, and I think it's because I have timeout in my useEffect.

Comment: Maybe a situation where your `useEffect()` should be a `useLayoutEffect()` instead, and without the `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use the fake timer and advance the time manually instead of waiting for the element to actually be done with the animation. This increases the actual test speed, and you have more control over how long the time actually needs to pass before assertion.

Here is an updated one. The result may differ depends on which UI library/framework you are using, so this may or may not work for you, but it has worked for me, so

```
beforeEach(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers('modern')
})

afterEach(() => {
    jest.runAllTimers()
    jest.useRealTimers()
})

test('testname', async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup()
    const { store } = renderWithProviders(<App />)
    const editBtn = screen.getByTestId('edit-item')
    await user.click(editBtn) // <-- opens popup
    const editPopupInput = screen.getByTestId('edit-popup-input')
    const savePopupBtn = screen.getByTestId('save-popup-btn')
    expect(editPopupInput).toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(savePopupBtn).toBeInTheDocument()
    await user.type(editPopupInput, 'text')
    expect(editPopupInput).toHaveValue('text')
    await user.click(await screen.findByTestId('save-popup-btn'))
    expect(store.getState().data.items[0].title).toEqual('text') // <-- click worked well

    jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000) // to fast forward animation effect

    // use waitFor instead, and use `queryBy...` instead of `getBy...` selector.
    await waitFor(() => screen.queryByTestId('save-popup-btn').not.toBeInTheDocument())
})
```

Comment: I believe, you should either use await waitFor and make your test async. Or you should use fakeTimers and advanceTimers, you should not have to use both.

Comment: Thank you, maybe this solution works, but adding just beforeEach and afterEach from example above breaks my tests and they don't stop at all. I think problem comes from vite. It doesn't work properly with jest+rtl.

Comment: @Mister_CK Not true, it was a bug a couple years ago but has been patched https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/661

Comment: @uhidga Using `useFakeTimer` is a very common practice in writing code. It might be an indication that something is potentially wrong with your other tests, or your could still try run the code i provided without the `useFakeTimer` and see if it works or now.

Comment: you could also add `jest.runAllTimers()` right before the `jest.useRealTimers()` and see it that works